# Fixing KeyError in Index

Tags: python, pandas, csv, keyerror

I am continually getting

```
runfile('C:/Users/GregL/.matplotlib/test of loops.py', wdir='C:/Users/GregL/.matplotlib')
c:\users\gregl\.matplotlib\test of loops.py:19: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
  mergeddata.z = mergeddata['central distance']
c:\users\gregl\.matplotlib\test of loops.py:20: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
  mergeddata.x = mergeddata['x par']
c:\users\gregl\.matplotlib\test of loops.py:21: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
  mergeddata.y = mergeddata['y rad']
c:\users\gregl\.matplotlib\test of loops.py:22: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
  mergeddata.ZMax = mergeddata ['Z Max']
c:\users\gregl\.matplotlib\test of loops.py:23: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
  mergeddata.ZMin = mergeddata ['Z Min']
c:\users\gregl\.matplotlib\test of loops.py:24: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
  mergeddata.Zup = mergeddata ['Upper Lim']
c:\users\gregl\.matplotlib\test of loops.py:25: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
  mergeddata.Zlow = mergeddata ['Lower Lim']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\GregL\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\gregl\.matplotlib\test of loops.py", line 53, in <module>
    surf=ax.scatter3D(x[z1],y[z1],z[z1],c='red',cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,s=.1,marker='x')

  File "C:\Users\GregL\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\series.py", line 984, in __getitem__
    return self._get_with(key)

  File "C:\Users\GregL\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\series.py", line 1024, in _get_with
    return self.loc[key]

  File "C:\Users\GregL\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 967, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)

  File "C:\Users\GregL\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1191, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)

  File "C:\Users\GregL\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1132, in _getitem_iterable
    keyarr, indexer = self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis)

  File "C:\Users\GregL\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1327, in _get_listlike_indexer
    keyarr, indexer = ax._get_indexer_strict(key, axis_name)

  File "C:\Users\GregL\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5782, in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)

  File "C:\Users\GregL\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5842, in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")

KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([      2313.3108334,     57.91915734032,      70.6299190667,\n                    120.02294505,      124.254986712, 243.31550280000002,\n              243.31550280000002,      146.105908289,      146.105908289,\n                   141.393578059,\n              ...\n                     383118.4458,        406598.8082,        466337.6262,\n                     485021.8653,        676614.4588,        816073.0216,\n                      1032968.11,        3354015.867,        7916505.371,\n                     7953742.675],\n             dtype='float64', length=8544)] are in the [index]"
```

I am trying to plot a 3D scatter graph from a csv file, but and the error seems to be that its not reading my Z Max column in the csv file. I don't really see any formatting issue in my csv file, and it works for plotting the full graph of my data. Where I am getting the error now is when I am trying to plot the error points. Z is a central distance, and Z Max/Z Min are the furthest and closest possible points. The code I am trying to use is below

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.colors as col
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pandas as pd

headers = ['name','ra','x rads','x par','dec','y rad','Parallax','Parallax Error','central distance','Z Max','Upper Lim','Z Min','Lower Lim']
mergeddata = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\GregL\Downloads\mergedata - no neg parallax #s (3).csv')

mergeddata.z = mergeddata['central distance']
mergeddata.x = mergeddata['x par']
mergeddata.y = mergeddata['y rad']
mergeddata.ZMax = mergeddata ['Z Max']
mergeddata.ZMin = mergeddata ['Z Min']
mergeddata.Zup = mergeddata ['Upper Lim']
mergeddata.Zlow = mergeddata ['Lower Lim']

x = mergeddata.x
y = mergeddata.y
z = mergeddata.z
ZMax = mergeddata.ZMax
ZMin = mergeddata.ZMin
Zup = mergeddata.Zup
Zlow = mergeddata.Zlow

t3 = (z >= 1695.477401) & (z <= 2313.310833)

e1 = (z <= 1695.477401) & (z <= 2313.310833) & (ZMax >= 1695.477301) & (ZMax <= (1.5*2313.310833)) 

e2 = (z <=1695.477401) & (z <= 2313.310833) & (ZMin >= (1.5*1695.477401)) & (ZMin <=2313.310833)

for z1 in e1:
    z1 = z + Zup
    
for z2 in e2:
    z2 = z - Zlow
    

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection ='3d')

surf=ax.scatter3D(x[t3],y[t3],z[t3],c='green',cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,s=.5,marker='^')
surf=ax.scatter3D(x[z1],y[z1],z[z1],c='red',cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,s=.1,marker='x')
surf=ax.scatter3D(x[z2],y[z2],z[z2],c='blue',cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,s=.1,marker='-')

ax.set_title('3D Data Distance Plot')

ax.set_zlim(-100,10000)
ax.set_xlim(-50,50)
ax.set_ylim(-50,50)

ax.set_xlabel('RA')
ax.set_ylabel('DEC')
ax.set_zlabel('CENTRAL DISTANCE')

plt.show()
```

For example, I want to plot the error values of the Z that are within that t3/e1/e2 range, so I am trying to just add a calculated Zup value which is the ZMax-Z and Zlow which is the Z-Zmin so that it can plot the points I want exactly in the e1/e2 range. Is the error in my csv file/wording? Or am I just doing this completely wrong?

[image: image of csv file]

Comment: Can you provide some data and the full traceback, please?

Comment: Sorry, do you just want the full console read out? Im new to python so I'm not familiar with all the terminology. If so I can edit the post. How to I get the CSV file so people can download it?

Comment: Yes. What is `surf=ax.scatter3D(x[z1],y[z1],z[z1],c='red',cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,s=.1,marker='x')`? `z1` does not appear in your code.

Comment: Oh sorry that was supposed to i1; I uploaded the wrong block it should be fixed now